# Preposition and tense-Homework

Tags: prepositions, homework, verb-forms

In today's exam, I had few grammar questions. I am doubtful in two questions. Please check my answers and correct the mistakes, if any.

1.Fill with suitable prepositions.

> There lived _ _ _ _ _ a forest a pride of lions _ _ _ _ _ several cubs

I wrote

> There lived in a forest a pride of lions with several cubs

2.Fill with suitable verb forms.

> Yarmuk _ _ _ _ French for the last 5 years but now he _ _ _ _ German.(learn)

I wrote

> Yarmuk has been learning French for the last 5 years but now he is learning German.

Am I right?

Comment: What does “I am doubtful in two questions” mean?

Comment: @tchrist It means that I am not sure whether I answered correctly or not. I need some hhelp to know the correct answer.

Comment: I know it's not what you were asking about, but you might like to note the difference between _few_ and _a few_. _A few_ is neutral: it just means a small number, without any implication about how many might have been expected. But _few_ emphasises the smallness of the number, suggesting that one might have expected more. So _I had few grammar questions_ implies something like "though I expected more" or "though you might have expected I would have more".

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. I was unaware about the difference. I was meant to say ` a few`.

Answer (score 1):

Both work just fine.  For the last one, I would have chosen the simpler verb studied/studies, but that's just how I read it.

What's the nature of the course work leading up to the exam?

Comment: Thanks for your remark. That's a part of school exams. I am in ninth grade.

Comment: A small thing is nagging me. Is it right to use `Yarmuk had been learning French ...`

Comment: Yes, though they mean different things:  "Had been learning French" is past tense.  "Has been learning French" is present tense.